# Can one say “gotten to like him”?

Tags: appropriate, phrase-usage

I came across the phrase *Gotten to like him* in one of the English movies. Is it appropriate and grammatical to say the following:

> Sarah has gotten to like him.

Comment: "Curiously, one of the reasons why gotten got (!) such a bad press in British English was John Galsworthy's failure to actually understand **how it was used in America,** believing (and writing) that all Americans used gotten instead of got on all occasions, which is simply not correct." [emphasis mine] http://www.miketodd.net/encyc/gotten.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Gotten* is an American word. It is used as the past-participle of get.

So, yes, it is appropriate and correct to say it, though the way you've used it sounds incorrect. Consider:

> Sarah has gotten to liking him.

Also, this is not really used outside of the US. In the UK (and most everywhere else) you would say:

> Sarah got to liking him.

Comment: past **participle**

Comment: **Sarah got to liking him.**- I'm not sure about this. I'm not a knowledgeable guy but I think it will change the tense of OP's phrase.

Comment: Better to call it an "Americanism" in the given context. The word exists in BrE as well (as the past participle). The meaning is **not quite the same** as the use of *pp* in AmE. The answer, therefore, is more complex than this.

Comment: @Kris ["As past participles of get, got and gotten both date back to Middle English. The form gotten is **not used in British English** but is very common in North American English, though even there it is often regarded as non-standard."](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gotten)

Comment: 'Sarah has gotten to like him' sounds like an Americanism to my British ears, but 'Sarah has gotten to liking him' sounds alien. 'Sarah has gotten round to liking him' sounds acceptable as an Americanism.

Comment: Right. You are almost there now. See also my comment at the OP.

Comment: @Tucker. It is certainly used in Britain by native speakers. Not 'used' in the sense 'always chosen', but 'used' in the sense 'chosen when considered suitable, as for effect'.

Comment: In the UK, *gotten* is normally just used in *ill-gotten* and *forgotten*. That's all.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Fair enough. Can't deny that. Also, on another note, I made a mistake because the OP posted *'Sarah has gotten to like him?'*, so I mistook the question mark as part of the statement instead.

Comment: Even within the USA, it's regional in its use, but it appears to be accepted as "correct" though not the only option. In the UK it also occurs regionally, but would be seen as dialect rather than as a form of standard English (other than the idioms already mentioned).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth "Sarah has gotten to liking him" can be used. Take in this context: "How's that mean ol' dog, Sarah? Still biting her new owner?", "Nah. Sarah has gotten to liking him." Just wanted to point that out. I think "gotten 'round" has become an accepted phrase. "He's gotten 'round to finally finishing the program."

Comment: In American English there are **two** past participles of _get_: _got_ **and** _gotten_ -- neither is **the** past participle. They occur in different circumstances, and there is rarely a choice as to which one to use. [My explanation of this phenomenon here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/gotten.html) gets the most hits of any file on my website; last month (May 2014) it was downloaded over 8000 times. Which suggests to me that the actual facts are largely unknown, but -- as usual -- vaguely but firmly stated opinion comes to the rescue.

Answer (score 1):

In a non-searchable and potentially ephemeral comment to the original posting, Professor Lawler kindly presented the following answer:

> In American English there are two past participles of *get*: *got* and *gotten* — neither is **the** past participle. They occur in different circumstances, and there is rarely a choice as to which one to use.
>
> [My explanation of this phenomenon here](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/aue/gotten.html) gets the most hits of any file on my website; last month (May 2014) it was downloaded over 8000 times.
>
> Which suggests to me that the actual facts are largely unknown, but — as usual — vaguely but firmly stated opinion comes to the rescue.

I’ve marked this posting Community Wiki because it is John’s answer not my own, and so I deserve no reputation from it.

Answer (score 0):

It is a common-enough idiom.  It suggests that her fondness for him has developed over time.

Comment: Very much there. We need to elaborate further, though.